# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, unit-testing, compiler-errors

I am using:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder
```

in a in an Android **library project (A)** that in turn is used in another **library project (B)**.

This works fine in the Android app that consumes library **project B**.

However, I have built an Android Test project to unit test the Android app - in particular the library project B classes.  When doing so I encounter the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder
```

I have included

```
commons-lang-2.6.jar
```

which contains the

```
org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder
```

namespace in library **project A** build path for export.

I have searched SO for this issue and found a number of posts on the `NoClassDefFoundError`, but none that have a situation with unit testing.

Comment: did you put it in the eclipse build path?

Comment: @blackbelt To which project should I put it to?

Comment: you should put the jar inside the libs folder. It will be autmatically loaded

Comment: @blackbelt  I put the jar in the lib folder of Project A.  Still get the NoClassDefFoundError error.

Comment: you have in the Eclipse build path?

Comment: @blackbelt, I am a little confused.  Where exactly is the Eclipse build path?

Comment: right click on the project name -> properties

Comment: Forgive my naivete, but I always thought of that as the project build path.  Did as you recommend and it still throws the error.

Comment: Did you put it in the libs folder of you test project?

Comment: @MichalPalczewski I added the commons-lang-2.6.jar to my test project build path and exported it.  I still get NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  After reviewing this [article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html), I realized that I needed both the jar from project A and the commons-lang-2.6.jar in the test project.  Adding BOTH jars to the build path and export resolved the issue.